# Method for fitting censored data in R

Tags: r, censoring, tobit-regression, astronomy

I have 320 data points - each has a redshift and a turnover-frequency, and I want to fit a correlation between them (a linear fit). However, 120 of the turnover-frequency values are upper limits. As shown below the relationship is very weak:
[image]

the red points have upper limits for their turnover-frequency value.
I would like to fit a straight line to this data that accounts for the upper limits. I think the tobit model in R can do this, but I'm not too sure (I'm new to R by the way); before I start with that, are there other methods in R I should consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have observations that assume the upper and lower limits of the possible observation range, then a tobit (= censored Gaussian) could be one possible way to go.

In R this and other censored regression models can be fitted in the `survival` package using the `survreg()` function. The manual page for the `?tobin` data set contains a worked example from the original left-censored Tobin data. For your data, you would have to flag the right-censored points that assume their upper limits with the `Surv()` function.

A convenience interface to `survreg()` that facilitates setting the upper and lower limit without calling `Surv()` by hand is the `tobit()` function in the `AER` package. By default, observations are assumed to be left-censored at zero and uncensored on the right but both limits can be changed easily. Observation-specific censoring points can also be used using `-Inf` or `Inf` for those points that are not left- or right-censored, respectively.

Comment: Thankyou, but does the tobit model handle data where there is a different upper limit for each censored data point?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant above with observation-specific censoring.